# PhoneGap/Cordova interrupted download when sleep, how to prevent

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have an iOS app using Cordova 2.5, and it has built in file download capability.
However when user puts device in sleep, or it just sleeps because of idle timer, the download gets interrupted and app crashes.

How to prevent going to sleep/interrupting downloads in PhoneGap/Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used BackgroundJS to deal with described situation

Answer (score 1):

You can try the power management plugin for iOS, seems like its been approved for phonegap build.
[Github link](https://github.com/simplec-dev/powermanagement/blob/a55652d0a622d7dd3629272c6428383d88f18531/README.md)
or [build docs](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/29)